# How to multiply the html fields on my mysql results?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

i have some divs of which my database results are shown there, having image, name and name of the album, but i'll be having 1000 of this kind of data to be displayed, does it mean i have to prepare a html having 1000 fields on my php ?

Here is my simple code

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM songs ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($resultCheck > 0) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
?>
<li>
<div><a href="single.html"><img src="images/<?php echo $row['cover_photo']; ? 
>" alt=""/></div>
</a>
<div class="slide-title"><h4><?php echo $row['song_name']; ?></div>
<div class="slide-title"><h4><?php echo $row['artist']; ?></div>
<div button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="button">BUY</div>
</li>
<?php
}
}
?>
```

Comment: If you want to display 1000 items on a page: yes.

Comment: That invalid HTML though: in that code you're missing `<ul>`, your `<div>` closes before the `<a>`, your `<h4>`s are not closed and I doubt that `<div button..>` will work

Comment: Besides code indenting and formatting also would do wonders for readability, understandability and maintainability

Comment: that's really painful, i just wanted simple divs but as long as the data increase in the database they will be generated according to the previous format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you do. Plus, you can do a pagination for limit(rows) per page 50. And if you really don't need all fields from db like id, or created_at and etc, don't use * in Select. Specify which fields you want to get. This will make query much faster as num of rows will grow